# PHP Echo _GET value to MySQL and filter results

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, forms

I have a search result page with a simple form to filter order of results, I want the form to filter:

ORDER BY - ASC or DESC - and PER PAGE LIMIT in the MySQL query

Here is the code to filter the order by I am trying to use

```
$order_by = mysqli_real_escape_string($database,$_GET['order_method']);
$query = mysqli_query($database,"SELECT * FROM `products` 
order by `<?php if(empty($order_by)){echo "id";}else{echo "$order_by"; ?>` ASC");
```

It is not working ... I get errors in >php line 22 and this line is the line of code above

The idea is that if the user comes to the default page I obviously get no $order_by so in this case the order by will be the default

```
echo "id"
```

But if the customer uses the html form to filter the results and I get the "order_by" the mysql query order by changes to the value the customer sends using the html form in this case

```
echo "$order_by"
```

I am trying many ways to do this but no one seems to work, any ideas would help a lot

Comment: Why Complicating Your Query?

Comment: You can't use php tags inside of a php section. Take them out. .

Comment: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even
[if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared statement and parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: So if I delete the <? and ?> tags it should work ?

Answer (score 1):

Your code:

```
$order_by = mysqli_real_escape_string($database,$_GET['order_method']);
$query = mysqli_query($database,"SELECT * FROM `products` 
order by `<?php if(empty($order_by)){echo "id";}else{echo "$order_by"; ?>` ASC");
```

The problem:

```
<?php if(empty($order_by)){echo "id";}else{echo "$order_by"; ?>
```

You are already in a PHP code block. You need to build up the query string using concatenation:

Try:

```
$order_by = mysqli_real_escape_string($database,$_GET['order_method']);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `products` order by `";

if(empty($order_by)){
  $sql .= "id";
} else {
  $sql .= $order_by;
}

$sql .="` ASC";

// Now you can execute the query
$query = mysqli_query($database,$query);
```

Comment: does I need to obligated use the // Now you can execute the query
$query = mysqli_query($database,$query);   too ?

Comment: It's to indicate that I'm building the query first, *then* executing the query. The original example attempts to build the query and execute it in the same step.